# configuring linux kernel with (hard-loaded, built in) currently loaded modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to build from source a recent Linux kernel (e.g. 4.13.4 in end of september 2017) on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 with all (or most) currently loaded modules configured as hard-built in the new kernel.

<sup>(I believe that I have read something like this somewhere, but can't remember where and can't find it)</sup>

It would be some `make configfromloadedmodules` (but of course it is not exactly `configfromloadedmodules` makefile target, but some other target that I did not easily find).

That is, for most (ideally all) *currently loaded* modules (as given by `lsmod`) it would answer `Y` (not `m`) for each of them at `make config` time and give me some good enough `.config`; but I don't want a bloated kernel with all drivers -even those that I don't use and which are not currently loaded- built in.

Does that exist, or was what I have probably read some wish or some non standard feature of experimental kernels?

This would avoid any `initrd` thing and give me a kernel suited for my hardware and habits.

The current kernel is a standard Debian one `4.12.0-2-amd64`, so I have its `/boot/config-4.12.0-2-amd64` (so I want to automatize the replacement of `CONFIG`xxx`=m` with `CONFIG`xxx`=y` there, according to the currently loaded modules, e.g. as given by `lsmod`).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46539515/841108) answer; I still believe that device trees are not essential to Linux, but they are a useful convenience.

A near variant of my question is how to *easily* configure a kernel, suited to my computer and hardware and set-up, without `ìnitrd`,  without any modules (e.g. with `CONFIG_MODULES=n`) and without (or with very few) useless drivers, which would work as nicely as my current Debian kernel.

Comment: Do you have the **.config** file for the current kernel?

Comment: Yes, see edited question

Comment: I normally don't suggest this, but for this case it seems relatively safe to edit the **.config** file, replacing the `=m` with `=y`.

Comment: But I want something to automate this based on `lsmod` output

Comment: It's not trivial to derive the  Kconfig symbol(s) from a loadable module name.  You probably need to find the **Makefile** to map the latter to the former.  How may times do you expect to perform this conversion?

Comment: I do remember having read that something has been tried, but I forgot what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe, you should read about "**make localmodconfig**" and "**make localyesconfig**" and use one as per your requirement.

[This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Modprobed-db), [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253245/what-does-make-localmodconfig-do) and [This](https://superuser.com/questions/146544/how-to-configure-a-linux-kernel-based-on-the-modules-currently-in-use) are helpful links.